# How to use two different versions of jar for two different dependencies

Tags: java, netty

I am using two different dependencies that need to use netty. One imports version 4.0.50 of netty and the other imports version 4.1.14. Neither can use the other one's version. Obviously there is a conflict here, how can I resolve this?

Thanks!

Comment: try to updtae the one import, or downgrade the other

Comment: Well, there are several options: different JVMs if possible (since probably easier), different classloaders (many application servers like Wildfly, Glassfish etc. do that), fix/upgrade/replace the dependencies etc.

Comment: @Thomas How can I use different classloaders can you provide some more detail?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not an expert in how to do that, that's why I mentioned application servers etc. There should be plenty of documentation on that though and the basic stuff isn't too complex: when a class definition is needed it's looked up in the current classloader hierarchy and if not found it's loaded into some level of that hierarchy. The more complex/substantial part would be how the dependencies are loaded and how the loaded classes (yours and those in the dependencies) are assigned to those classloaders.

Comment: @Thomas Ok thanks. How about running separate JVMs? I'm using the Spring framework and could create two different poms and run them on separate servers, but how would they be able to interact with each other? I'm not sure how to do that!

Comment: Well, you don't have to run the applications on different servers but that's up to you. How they interact is up to you as well but the most common of modern aproaches would probably be via REST webservices (although there are a lot of other ways like SOAP, RPC, etc.)

Comment: @Thomas ok do you have any pointers to any articles about running different JVMs that interact with each other on the same machine?

Comment: Well there are so many different ways that it shouldn't be hard to find something that fits your requirements (which I don't know). Running multiple JVMs on the same machine is a no-brainer (just run them), interaction between the two depends on how you want them to interact. Many setups will require you to use different ports, e.g. 8080 for JVM 1 and 8081 for JVM 2, but the what and how again depend on the setup you want to achieve and the requirements and capabilities of your software.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to just use 4.1.14, that should also work as dependency for the other that uses 4.0.50. If it not works you can still shade the dependencies.